# pst-map2d - unrecoverable error

Tags: pstricks, pst-geo

I am using this piece of code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-map2d}


\begin{document}

{\psset{xunit=0.5, yunit =0.5}
\begin{pspicture}*(-9,-9)(10 ,9)
\WorldMap[maillage = false]
\end{pspicture}}

\end{document}
```

to generate a simple map; however, when compiling an error regarding GLP Ghostscript says:

```
Unrecoverable error, exit code 1.
```

I tried to run the shown code on both PC and MAC but it seems the compilers need extra seetings, or I am not aware of something. Currently, I compile this using LaTeX->DVIPS->PS2PDF.

Comment: A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 2):

you have to specify the path where the data files can be found, eg for TeXLive 2013/14 (XXXX) under Linux

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-map2d}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=0.5}
\begin{pspicture*}(-9,-9)(10,9)
\WorldMap[path=/usr/local/texlive/XXXX/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-geo/data,
  maillage=false]
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

You can also use `xelatex` instead of the sequence `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

[image]

If you are using Linux, then you can set a link from your documents directory to the data dir. Don't know if this is also possible on Windows and Mac. When using `ps2pdf` you have to use the optional argument `-dNOSAFER` otherwise ghostscript won't run external files (for some security reason)

Comment: Why is it the path needs to be specified explicitly in this case, For eg: PSTricks can access `/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pstricks/images/tiger.pdf`

Comment: that one is used on `pdftex` level, the path for the data is used by PostScript, in this case by `ghostscript` for converting it to pdf. And it knows nothing about path setting in TeX

Comment: It is a cumbersome feature.

Answer (score 1):

For all users who still have a problem with pst-map2d. I came to this page because I received the same error message and found no solution.

**Solution:** `pst-map2d` is no longer used. It is included in `pst-geo`. After deactivating the old package Ghostview does not cause any problems anymore.